HTML5 canvas ellipse draws incorrectly
HTML5 Canvas seems to have an error when drawing an ellipse. Consider this simple example:
For me this occurs in Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox or Safari.


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

function draw(val) {
  ctx.moveTo(160, 110);
  ctx.lineTo(val, 60.1418);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.ellipse(110, 110, 50, 50, 0, 4.63705, 0, true);
  ctx.stroke();
}
draw(106.2367);
//draw(106.236);
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" />



I get the following image as a result:

And if I simply replace draw(106.2367) with draw(106.236), I get a completely different result:

I know this issue can be fixed by removing ctx.closePath(), but I want to know why this happened in the first place. Is this a bug?

Open an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/

Please d'on't use transparency in your picture. I use SO with Dark-mode preference for display (as many) and the background is black.

That would be a non-regression, going back as far as M93 it still reproduced. If you absolutely need it to work, my path2D-inspection manages to avoid the bug (by drawing 2 curves for the ellipse), but it's gonna make everything slower: https://jsfiddle.net/h4g26j3f/

@Kaiido Interesting. What do you mean by "non-regression" and M93?

I mean the bug has always been there, it's not like a recent change introduced it. M93 is what corresponds to Chrome 93, i.e. a quite old version.
